# obtain the number of rows been selected from ListView

Tags: c#, sql, listview

I want to get the number of rows selected or the SQL return code. The idea is not to do the `listview1.dataBind` when nothing has been returned. I cannot execute the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` here, I know.  I would like to get something similar.

```
private void ListApointement(string sChoixDdl)
{
    using (ApointementDataContext db = new ApointementDataContext())
    {
        var aptItems = from Apointement in db.Apointement 
                       where Apointement.doctorName == sChoiceDdl && 
                             Apointement.isAvailable == true && 
                             Apointement.date >= DateTime.Now 
                       select Apointement;

                  ListView1.DataSourceID = null;
                  ListView1.DataSource = aptItems;

//I want to get the number or rows which have been selected or the sql return code.
                  int numberOfRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

                  ListView1.DataBind();

    };
}
```

Comment: You want the number of records returned by the `linq` query you use already in the sample or you need to execute other query?

Comment: the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery is not Working !

Comment: where is your command string???

Comment: @Selman22  I don't understand which string you want

Comment: Try `aptItems.Count()`

Comment: I want to see cmd definition

Comment: aptItems.Count() does what I want.  Got a problem if I don't do the ListView1.DataBind() because the count is not greater than 0   Cannot access a disposed object.   I tried to put an else with ListView1.Dispose();  but it doesn't fix the problem. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you please be a little more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are I fixed this issue.  I left the DataBind() outside the if statement because it was causing an error "Cannot access a disposed object."  after in the program.   I decided to generate an empty ListView + an error message.

```
                  ListView1.DataSourceID = null;
                  ListView1.DataSource = rdvItems;

                  int numberOfRecords = rdvItems.Count();
                  if (numberOfRecords == 0)
                  {
                      lblMessage.Text = "No Apointement are available";

                  }


                  ListView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
if (aptItems.Count() > 0)
    ListView1.DataBind();
```